# android youtube data api

Tags: android, api, youtube

I am trying to find the details of a youtube video through its ID (example ->
 yb7E4lQIaZI). I read that if we just want the details we can use the api_key from the developer console. if we want to do operations such as upload a video we need to use oauth. I just want to go with the firstcase. i just need the details of the video like thumnail url and title which i want to show in a listview.

I am trying to do this with the use of my api_key but i cant make it to work.The last line (system.out.println) is not printing anything. The code i have written is below

```
    try {

        YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new 
        HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            }
        }).setApplicationName("my_project").build();

        HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("part", "snippet,contentDetails,statistics");
        parameters.put("id", "yb7E4lQIaZI");

        YouTube.Videos.List videosListByIdRequest = youtube.videos().list(parameters.get("part").toString());
        videosListByIdRequest.setKey(MY_API_KEY_FROM_DEVELOPER_CONSOLE);
        if (parameters.containsKey("id") && parameters.get("id") != "") {
            videosListByIdRequest.setId(parameters.get("id").toString());
        }

        VideoListResponse response = videosListByIdRequest.execute();
        System.out.println(response);


    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : " + e.getDetails().getMessage());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When i run the debug it exits after the line 'VideoListResponse response = videosListByIdRequest.execute();' and doesnot go to the line 'System.out.println(response)'.

The app doesnot crash or show any error, it just doesnt go to the 'system.out.print' line

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you have added internet permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Yes..i have already added..i can run the video but cant get the youtube data api to work